# Android XML Common Elements between pages? Frames?

Tags: android, xml, header, skinning

I am skinning an app and I was wondering if there was a way to keep common elements the same between XML layouts without copying the same code around all the time.

For instance, I have a header and footer and background that will be the same between most pages. Can I make a "common" xml containing the header and footer and just load the individual page like a frame inside of it?

I'm not sure how I would reference that individual page within the XML. Maybe I could change an ID from the java side in an onCreate function, although it seems like more work now, if I changed something on the header and footer in the future I wouldn't have to change every Activity of the app.

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the inclue tag you're looking for. Example:

```
<include layout="@layout/bar_header_top" />
```

Comment: Okay, I rearranged things and put the include in, renders fine in the XML Builder, crashes when actual app loader right at setContent(R.layout.x), googling why this might happen, let me know if you have any insight, thank you

Comment: It might certainly help if you pasted in the stacktrace of the crash from logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Java class that extends a View that holds all header elements and one that holds all footer elements and implement them in every view like this

```
<LinearLayout>

    <com.[package].[classname of header] />

    -- content here --

    <com.[package].[clasname of footer] />

</LinearLayout>
```